# Hiding a cell with a Hidden Field

Tags: asp.net

In my GridView, I am using a Hidden Field to store some data that is not supposed to be seen by the user:

```
                                    <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Название" HeaderText="Название" ItemStyle-Width="250px" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RDName" HeaderText="РД" ItemStyle-Width="250px" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="RD_ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RD_ID") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
```

I have a problem with this. Though the data is not seen in the GridView, the additional empty cell is still there. Could you please tell me how I can hide it completely?
Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you do it like this?

```
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Название" HeaderText="Название" ItemStyle-Width="250px" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="РД" ItemStyle-Width="250px" HeaderStyle-Width="250px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="RD_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RDName") %>' />
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="RD_ID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("RD_ID") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always put the hidden element alongside with any TemplateField ItemTemplate object. You don't have to create a cell to contain the hidden element.